# How to extract a value inside column in certain pattern in oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to extract data in the format (465797,461396) from (',7809628#465797,7809628#461396,') data. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DBFiddle][1]

```
select
  ltrim(
    regexp_replace(
        ',7809628#465797,7809628#461396,'
       ,'[^#]*#(\d+),'
       ,',\1')
    ,','
  ) new_str
from dual;
```

Results:

```
NEW_STR
-------------
465797,461396
```

Regexp `'[^#]*#(\d+),'`:

`[^#]*` - any number of any symbols except '#'
`(\d+)` - digits, one or more digits, `()` - marks it as a group
and comma after that.

So it finds *(any symbols except #, then #, then one or more digits, then comma)* and replaces all found substrings to comma and found "one or more digits"(the only group in the expression). Then `ltrim` removes extra comma in the beggining.
[1]: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f66505cd2746a1387e41ec91d6c7df3a

Comment: Data is correct , can you please explain how it is working?

Comment: @sharmishtha done, check the updated answer

Comment: I have a query. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71585623/function-retuning-sys-refcursor

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple string functions (which may be more to type than with a regular expression but is likely to execute quicker):

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(value, hash1 + 1, comma2 - hash1 - 1)
       || ',' ||
       SUBSTR(value, hash2 + 1, comma3 - hash2 - 1) AS parsed_value
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR(value, '#', 1, 1) AS hash1,
         INSTR(value, '#', 1, 2) AS hash2,
         INSTR(value, ',', 1, 2) AS comma2,
         INSTR(value, ',', 1, 3) AS comma3
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT ',7809628#465797,7809628#461396,' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PARSED_VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 465797,461396 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0a43809ca8b7f8d0676ec9ff4a432d08)*